# Mod Magic Trick for 8

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The question is: Find the mod magic trick for 8. Explain why your trick works and describe you answer using a nine digit number: abcdefghi.

So what I have figured out is that the mod trick for 8 is to reduce the last 3 digits in mod 8 to get the remainder. However I do not know how to represent this without using a real number.

Comment: Can you just say that $ABCDEFGHI = ABCDEF000+GHI = ABCDEF \times 1000 + GHI = ABCDEF \times 8 \times 128 + GHI \equiv GHI \pmod 8$?

Comment: @BrianTung I assume you mean $125$ not $128$.

Comment: @KevinLong: Indeed I do mean $125$—thanks for the catch!